# What is difference between Primary Key and Composite Key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I Would like to know the difference between these two Queries:

1)

```
CREATE TABLE tblSample
   (
   T_Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   ID INT ,
   BNO INT
   )
```

2)

```
CREATE TABLE tblSample
  (
  T_Id INT,
  ID INT,
  BNO INT,
  CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY(T_Id,ID,BNO)
  )
```

Comment: Difference is first syntax is invalid and second syntax is valid. Second is called as composite primary key

Comment: You can only have one primary key on a table. That PK can contain more than one field though (as per your second example)

Comment: which DB syntax is this? there can only be 1 primary key per table, it can be composite (consisting of multiple columns) or not (consisting of only 1 column)

Comment: @sai try to think about something like: T_ID - PK, (ID, BNO) - unique constraint.

Comment: You can have multiple UNIQUE NOT NULL columns which logically behave as PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is not correct, you can have only one primary key. However you can have multiple unique keys per table.

For second one you specify composite key which means that combination of all 3 values should be unique e.g.

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
```

considers as valid values even that 2 first columns have same values.